# search condition to find if logs are present for previous hour.

Tags: unix

I am creating one unix script to check if logs are generated for one of our job. logs are getting save in the file with the timestamp like

```
2017 Apr 11 13:09:54:384 - Required information will be present here.
2017 Apr 11 13:17:31:578 - Required information will be present here.
```

we are stuck on the seach condition which will check if logs are present for the previous hour.

How I can write this if statement which will check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using `grep` & `date`:

```
grep -c "^$(date -d '-1 hour' '+%Y %b %d %H:')"
```

Here, `date` command generates timestamp that matches with log file. Then, `grep` for the timestamp in log file. `-c` prints a count of matching lines of file.

Comment: that looks shorter indeed... :) - I would just note that the grep should probably search only at the beginning of each line in order to avoid that the date/time string appears accidentally in the body of some of the log messages associated with possibly different dates...

Answer (score 1):

it's perhaps a bit dirty solution, but you could construct first the "prefix" for the previous hour, i.e., `2017 Apr 11 12` and then check how many lines in the log file match:

```
#get the prefix
prefix=$(date -d'-1 hour' +'%Y %b %d %H')

#count matching lines
cnt=$(gawk -F':' "\$1==\"$prefix\"" test.log | wc -l)
echo $cnt
```

Assuming that `test.log` contains

```
2017 Apr 11 12:09:54:384 - Required information will be present here.
2017 Apr 11 13:17:31:578 - Required information will be present here.
```

then the value of the variable `cnt` above will be 1 (if the date command yields `2017 Apr 11 12`). So then you could branch your script on the basis of `$cnt`...

Comment: Thanks Ewcz but can you please explain why did you called it a bit dirty solution? If you could provide some other approch it will be very helpful.

Comment: @Wolfgang I meant a bit dirty, because it's not very robust, for example it assumes that the date/time produced by `date` is in the same timezone as the times in the log - I guess a more systematic solution would be to write an, e.g., Python script to handle these possible "surprises". But if the log files are guaranteed to be well-formed, then the solution should be ok, I suppose...

Comment: Thanks Ewcz. Logs are guaranteed generating in this format only.